# grouping by in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

In my database there is a column named game_id, I want to sum the other values ​​based on the group by game_id. But I have a problem that I have game_id 1999 and game_id 19999 their values ​​are different but It is same game. I am looking for a solution on how to group these two game_id together.

[image]

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images. And take a look at [mcve] before you start.

Comment: How do you know thy are the same game?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the value to the desired value in order to make your groupby statement work as you wish.

```
UPDATE table_name
SET game_id = 1999
WHERE game_id = 19999;
```

Comment: The problem is that the table has a lot of rows and it is added every minute, unable to update every API call

Comment: SQL by itself is limited in its ability to fix the problem you describe. You have 2 main options to fix this problem: 1. The SQL way is to use the code I mentioned above before every query that involves the game_id as a relevant factor for a groupby statement and such. 2. Web development can fix this problem by re-define the game id '19999' as '1999' and that way the problem will just disapear.

Comment: There is another way around this problem yet I think it will be less efficient than just using the update table method. You can use CASE statements in order to create a new column which contains the game_id for each game, and pre-define every game_id which is 19999 as 1999. Again, this solution is not as efficient and it seems like the best way to solve this problem is through backend engineering. If you don't have access to the DB schema, the 1st SQL solution I mentioned will definitely do the job.

Answer (score 0):

You can use case when and temp table

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT [name] FROM tempdb.sys.tables WHERE [name] like '#LocalTempTablo%') 
BEGIN
   DROP TABLE #LocalTempTablo;
END;

CREATE TABLE #LocalTempTablo
(
    game_id int, 
    sumexample int
)

INSERT INTO #LocalTempTablo SELECT CASE WHEN game_id=1999 or game_id=19999 THEN 1999 ELSE 1999 END, SUM(sumexample) FROM games WHERE game_id=1999 or game_id=19999
GROUP BY game_id

SELECT game_id, SUM(sumexample) FROM #LocalTempTablo
GROUP BY game_id
```

Answer (score 0):

If these are the specific games that need to be combined you can use a `case` expression:

```
select (case when game_id = 19999 then 1999 else game_id end) as imputed_game_id,
       sum(score)  -- or whatever
from t
group by imputed_game_id;
```

You can also handle this with a replacement table -- perhaps built directly into the query:

```
select coalesce(v.new_game_id, t.game_id) as imputed_game_id,
       . . .
from t left join
     (values (19999, 1999)
     ) v(game_id, new_game_id)
     on t.game_id = v.game_id
group by imputed_game_id;
```

This is handy for replacing multiple `game_id`s.